# Get software's information in WiX from software

Tags: wix

In my WiX file I have it "extract" the software version using `!(bind.fileVersion.MyFile)`. I would like to do the same with other information from the software like company name or software name. Is there a way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WiX.chm documents all the standard binder variables at the bottom of the topic titled `Linker (light)`. It does not appear the those pieces of information are available.  However, it might be something you could work with the [WiX toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) community with to get the code added.